# case statement in t-sql

Tags: sql, case

I have table similar to:

```
Create Table #test (Letter varchar(5), Products varchar(30))

Insert into #test (Letter, Products)
Values ('A','B,C,D,E,F'),('B','B,C,D,E,F'),('G','B,C,D,E,F'),('Z','B,C,D,E,F'),('E','B,C,D,E,F')
```

Is it possible to write a CASE Statement which will check if the list in the 'Products' column contain a letter from 'Letter' column?

Thanks

Comment: The comma values are a bad idea, can't you use a mapping table? That said `where charindex(',' + Letter + ',', ',' + Products + ',') > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query

```
Select *, Case When (charindex(Letter, Products, 0)>0) Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End AS [Y/N] from #test
```

Comment: The same problem here, works until OP uses more than one letter(it's already `varchar(5)`).

Answer (score 0):

I think i managed to do the trick:

```
CASE WHEN Products LIKE '%'+Letter+'%' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
```

Comment: This might work with a single character but not with strings.

Comment: but Letter column will always have only one charecter

Comment: You must know it because it's your reqirement. However, you have already used `varchar(5)` instead of `CHAR(1)`. So it not seems to be set in stone. I just wanted to note that even if it seems to work it would stop working once you have more than one letter. And the worst is that you would not even realize it.

Comment: @Tim you are right. my fault that didn't write about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXISTS` with a split-function:

```
SELECT Letter, Products,
       ContainsLetter = CASE WHEN EXISTS
       (
          SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Split(t1.Products, ',')s
          WHERE s.Item = Letter
       )
        THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END 
FROM #test t1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/477af/7/0)</kbd>

Here is the one i'm using on SQL-Server 2005:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @ItemTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(250))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```